# The probability that Student $1$ performs better than Student $2$ on an examination

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose there's a exam with 5 questions.
If the probability that Student $1$ correctly answers question $i$ is $P_{1.i}$, then

$P_{1.1} = 0.3$ , $P_{1.2} = 0.4$ , $P_{1.3} = 0.9$, $P_{1.4} = 0.7$ , $P_{1.5} = 0.1$

For Student $2$,

$P_{2.1} = 0.4$ , $P_{2.2} = 0.5$ , $P_{2.3} = 0.2$, $P_{2.4} = 0.8$ , $P_{2.5} = 0.1$

What is the probability that Student $1$ performs better than Student $2$ ?

How to solve something like that? I want an expression to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Compute all probabilities $P(C_i = j)$ where $C_i$ is the number of correct questions scored by student $i$. These are just sums of products of the $P_{i,j}$ really. Then sum all $P(C_1 = j)P(C_2 = k)$ over all pairs $j > k$ that are allowed. This is allowed by independence of the scores of both students.

E.g. to compute the probability that student 1 has 2 correct answers, consider all combinations of two answers out of the five. Say one of these is $\{i,j\}$, which means that student $1$ answers questions $i$ and $j$ correctly and the others incorrectly. The chance of exactly that happening is $P_{1,i} \times P_{1,j}$ times all factors $(1-P_{1,n})$ where $n \neq i,j$. And this we have to do for all $\binom{5}{2}$ sets of possible $\{i,j\}$ to compute $P(C_1 = 2)$.

This is quite tedious to do by hand, so I wrote a [program](https://gist.github.com/HendrikSikke/f81cf3c60de6f138f797241fb0189700):

The results were:

`P student 1 has 0 correct = 0.011340
P student 2 has 0 correct = 0.043200
P student 1 has 1 correct = 0.142200
P student 2 has 1 correct = 0.260400
P student 1 has 2 correct = 0.397800
P student 2 has 2 correct = 0.406400
P student 1 has 3 correct = 0.340000
P student 2 has 3 correct = 0.236400
P student 1 has 4 correct = 0.101100
P student 2 has 4 correct = 0.050400
P student 1 has 5 correct = 0.007560
P student 2 has 5 correct = 0.003200
1 does better with probability 0.471532
2 does better with probability 0.243788
equal score with probability 0.284680`

Comment: What is the mathematical expression to do this? $0.3 \cdot 0.4 \cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.7 \cdot 0.1 + 0.4 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 0.2 \cdot 0.8 \cdot 0.1$ ?  then what?

Comment: If you have been studying normal approximations, then maybe you need to find $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i^2$ for the total number correct by Student $i.$ Then find the mean $\mu_d = \mu_1-\mu_2$ difference between Student 1's total and Student2's and also $\sigma_d^2 = \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2$ for that difference. Finally, assume the difference is nearly normal with $\mu_d$ and $\sigma_d^2.$

Comment: Actually I don't know none of this. It's suppose to use basic concepts of probability.

Comment: Well, then: I assume Student 1's score is the number correct. Similarly, for Student 2. // If all questions equally difficult for each, you would be comparing BINOM(5, p) with BINOM(5, q), where $p > q.$ Because questions differ, it will be messier. But would you know how to answer the Problem if both students had binomial scores?

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** I wish you success with @HennoBrandsma's approach (+1). It seems there will be some bookkeeping in considering
all the possibilties. In case it is of any use (e.g., for checking intermediate results), here are simulated
distributions for Student 1, Student 2, and Difference scores.

It is
reasonable to expect the simulated probabilities to be accurate to two
or three places.

Although Student 1 will do slightly better *on average,* it seems that there is slightly less than a 50:50 chance for
Student 1 to do *better* than Student 2. However, there are about 3 chances in 4 Student 1 will do *as well or better.*

```
set.seed(429)
m = 10^6;  p1=c(3,4,9,7,1)/10;  p2=c(4,5,2,8,1)/10
s1 = replicate(10^6, sum(rbinom(5, 1, p1)))
round(table(s1)/m,3)
s1
    0     1     2     3     4     5 
0.011 0.142 0.398 0.340 0.101 0.008 
s2 = replicate(10^6, sum(rbinom(5, 1, p2)))
round(table(s2)/m,3)
s2
    0     1     2     3     4     5 
0.043 0.260 0.407 0.236 0.051 0.003 
d = s1 - s2
round(table(d)/m,3)
d
   -5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5 
0.000 0.001 0.011 0.060 0.172 0.285 0.272 0.148 0.044 0.006 0.000 

mean(s1 > s2)
[1] 0.471404
mean(s1 >= s2)
[1] 0.756087


par(mfrow=c(1,3))
 hist(s1, prob=T, br=(0:6)-.5, col="skyblue2", main="Student 1 Scores")
 hist(s2, prob=T, br=(0:6)-.5, col="skyblue2", main="Student 2 Scores")
 hist(d, prob=T, br=(-5:6)-.5, col="skyblue2", main="Difference in Scores")
  abline(v = .5, col="red", lwd=3, lty="dashed")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: The results of the simulation nicely match those of my C-program.